# Setting up Version Control on my Development Server

Tags: version-control, svn

I'm looking into the possibilities of integrating Version Control so that me and my team can work on code at the same time without having to worry about overwriting each others work. Previously this was easy to maintain as there were only three of us. However as our team has now grown it's become a key consideration moving forward.

I had previously worked with SVN using Springloops. The company paid a monthly fee to store the versions on their server and Springloops provided a web interface to work with the repositories.

However, I'd like to move away from using a third party and set up SVN on my own server for the team to work with. I'm wondering if this is possible and if so is it easy enough to achieve?

Security is a big issue for us and that is why we would prefer to host our code ourselves.

I'm wondering if anyone has some advice on this and possible other things to consider?

Comment: Yup, easy to do. So easy, that a simple google will provide numerous tutorials, so why bother asking here?  If you are asking _which_ VCS to use, then http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  might be a better site to ask. If you are co-located, then Subversion might well be "best", if remotely located,  then GIT. I _personally_ use http://www.plasticscm.com/home.html which is good for distributed, and has a great merge engine and great GUI features (http://www.plasticscm.com/gallery.html). At the end of the day, you will have to try a few out & choose the piece of string that suits you best.

Comment: I asked here because I'd like to get advice from the programming community with best practices. I of course did google and found a large amount of information on the different types of VC both centralised and decentralised. However some articles were quite old dating back to around 2008-09, whereas here the feedback is up to date. Also I'm not so much looking for tutorials as much as looking for what people feel is the best option to explore. Thank you for your answer though, I've never heard of that SE so I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if this is possible

Yes. Apache+SVN is a question of hours with SVN Book, svnserve'd server (but I'll recommend Apache-way) - minutes

> and if so is it easy enough to achieve?

Yes